# Create dropdown menu signup page with devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I would like to create a dropdown menu for a list of countries in my signup page with devise. I understand that I need to create a migration

```
rails g migration add_countries_to_user country:string
```

and then I have to use create the form in my view page

```
<%= f.select :countries, options_for_select(%w[Alfganistan, Albania, Algeria...]) %>
```

I would like to know if my form correct and where can I put the countries list in because it is not right to write 200+ countries in the view page right?

Thanks.

Comment: For countries you can use this https://github.com/stefanpenner/country_select

Comment: use a search field, and scroll bar to list .

Comment: check for jquery auto-complete

Comment: Put in config/initializers/constants.rb like COUNTRY = [Alfganistan, Albania, Algeria...]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested, you can use [country_select](https://github.com/stefanpenner/country_select). Or, you can do it on your own as:

Create an initializer which contains list of countries (or anything in particular you want) `config/initializers/countries.yml`

```
countries:
  - Afghanistan
  - United States
  - ...
```

Load it in database by creating a rake task as:
`lib/tasks/load_countries.rb`

```
namespace :db do
  desc "Loads countries in database"
  task :load_countries => :environment do |t|
    countries_list = YAML.load("#{Rails.root}/config/initializers/countries.yml")['countries']
    countries.each do |country|
      Country.find_or_create_by_name(country)
    end
  end
end
```

Whenever you add any countries in `yml`, you can populate it by invoking this rake task: `rake db:load_countries`.

Maintain a model `Country` :

```
class Country < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :name, presence: true, uniqueness: { case_insensitive: true }
end
```

I am considering that a user `belongs_to` 1 country above, and a country `has_many` users. In your view, :

```
f.select :country, options_from_collection_for_select(Country.all, :id, :name)
```

**Note**: I am using association approach above, since it will make it easier to make queries against this field in future, unlike saving an actual string in user.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [country_select](https://github.com/stefanpenner/country_select) gem.

```
# Gemfile
gem 'country_select'
```

form:

```
country_select("user", "country")
```

Comment: Ok thanks. But what if my data is not countries, but random Item1, Item2... where can I store the data and create a variable to put in views? Thanks.

Comment: Usually as records in a database. But could also be in a class constant for example `f.select :season, options_for_select(Season::ALL)` for a fixed and finite number of options.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from gem and Countries read from YML.

One more option is creating a method in your helper

File : app/helpers/country_helper.rb

```
def get_countries
  {:1=>Africa,:2=>"America"}
end
```

In Views you can use this way

```
<%= options_from_collection_for_select(get_countries, :id, :name) %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Look up rails cast #88 revised dynamic select menus. What you need is method call grouped_collection_select in which you will map out the item you need based on how they corresponded to one another

Answer (score 0):

You could do this as a helper method. eg, in your `users_helper.rb` you could list the selections:

```
def country_options
    [
        ['Afghanistan'],
        ['Albania'],
            ...
        ['Zimbabwe']
    ]
end
```

Then, your selector pulls from that helper method:

```
<%= f.select :country, options_for_select(country_options), { prompt: 'Choose Country' } %>
```